Is .NET 8 backwards compatible with .NET 7?
In my workplace we've been told that the .NET 7 runtimes in our servers will be uninstalled at the end of the month because support for .NET 7 has ended. They're going to install the latest .NET 8 hosting bundle.
All of our apps hosted in our servers run with .NET 7; we plan to update them to .NET 8, but that's going to take some time.
If they uninstall 7 and install the runtimes for 8, are we in trouble?
I looked around and I found that .NET 8 is backwards compatible with .NET 6, but nothing about 7 being the same case.

Supposing that it isn't - is it that much of a trouble for you to update your projects and recompile and republish?


If they uninstall 7 and install the runtimes for 8, are we in trouble?

A bit - by default runtime supports only the minor version roll-forward (i.e. 7.x.x will not roll-forward to 8.x.x), but this can be controlled via several roll-forward options, for example by specifying
<PropertyGroup>
    <RollForward>LatestMajor</RollForward>
</PropertyGroup>

Or via --roll-forward switch for dotnet run (though was not able to make it work in docker):
dotnet myapp.dll --roll-forward LatestMajor

Note that in general upgrading/recompilation is highly recommended - see the .NET Runtime compatibility docs.
See also Major-version runtime roll forward.

The-new-normal, post-.NET Core, can be described as a treadmill - or a death-march - this is going to be a huge problem for orgs that can't afford to actively maintain and update every project/program/application they have - does Microsoft have a plan for accomodating orgs that want to be able to write a program once, then leave it alone for 5+ years and expect it to still work, a la VB6 programs on Windows 11?
